# LAB colors functioning in an unexpected way

Tags: color

I was trying to make a program that calculates the brightness of a diffraction pattern, when I encountered this while using LAB Colors:
So `LABColor[0.01,0.8,0.8]` will give out a natural black color, but `LABColor[0.01,0,-1]` should also do that, but instead, it would surprisingly give out a bright blue color.
I tried other colors, and the only thing I know now is that the unusual brightness only occurs to `b->1` and `b->-1`.

[image: the problem, on far left]

the problem occurs on the far left of the image. Why? Shouldn't every color be black with `l->0`?
So I made another attempt with `l->-1`, and that did show that all the colors are black, but their RGB color decreases in different scales, rendering l useless in deciding whether the color is bright or not...

Comment: The issue is still present in MMA 11.3. I have contacted support...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more an extended comment than an answer. Yes, something seems to be wrong. Let us suppose, we represent the plane $L=0$, all the squares should be black:

```
Graphics[DeleteDuplicates@{{LABColor[#], Rectangle[Rest@#, Rest@# + {.2, .2}]} & /@
Tuples[{ConstantArray[0, 5], Range[-1, 1, .4], Range[-1, 1, .4]}]}, Axes -> True, 
AxesLabel -> {"a", "b"}]
```

[image]

But they are not. Therefore, let us investigate their RGB conversion. If $L=0$ means that all the coordinates in RGB should be zero also. However:

```
ColorConvert[DeleteDuplicates@(LABColor[#] & /@ Tuples[{ConstantArray[0, 6],
Range[-1, 1, .4], Range[-1, 1, .4]}]), "RGB"] // Chop[#, 10^-4] & // InputForm

(* {RGBColor[0, 0.07978506283947867, 0.5847606693969404], 
    RGBColor[0, 0.029956707406784244, 0.3447675409720798], 
    RGBColor[0, 0.004804407681413552, 0.13147226039098525], 
    RGBColor[0, 0, 0], 
    RGBColor[0, 0, 0], 
    RGBColor[0, 0, 0], 
    RGBColor[0, 0.07978506283947867, 0.5847606693969404], 
    RGBColor[0, 0.029956707406784244, 0.3447675409720798], 
    RGBColor[0, 0.004804407681413552, 0.13147226039098525], 
    RGBColor[0, 0, 0], 
    RGBColor[0, 0, 0], 
    RGBColor[0, 0, 0], 
    RGBColor[0, 0.07978506283947867, 0.5847606693969404], 
    RGBColor[0, 0.029956707406784244, 0.3447675409720798], 
    RGBColor[0, 0.004804407681413552, 0.13147226039098525], 
    RGBColor[0, 0, 0], 
    RGBColor[0, 0, 0], 
    RGBColor[0, 0, 0], 
    RGBColor[0, 0.02996327773049831, 0.5850760888790785], 
    RGBColor[0, 0, 0.3453763338813659], 
    RGBColor[0.10029469805817337, 0, 0.1332331739778148], 
    RGBColor[0.1309857317647039, 0, 0.004603936794368831], 
    RGBColor[0.1309857317647039, 0, 0.004603936794368831], 
    RGBColor[0.1309857317647039, 0, 0.004603936794368831], 
    RGBColor[0, 0, 0.5858135021464239], 
    RGBColor[0.23851504852018163, 0, 0.1372670806596635], 
    RGBColor[0.2524245138829351, 0, 0.015379827894536315], 
    RGBColor[0.2524245138829351, 0, 0.015379827894536315], 
    RGBColor[0.2524245138829351, 0, 0.015379827894536315], 
    RGBColor[0.10917014559406288, 0, 0.5871250115245642], 
    RGBColor[0.31825963178832845, 0, 0.3493098968135841], 
    RGBColor[0.3674034699089572, 0, 0.1441775650469683], 
    RGBColor[0.37591747422303856, 0, 0.034587975350480686], 
    RGBColor[0.37591747422303856, 0, 0.034587975350480686], 
    RGBColor[0.37591747422303856, 0, 0.034587975350480686]}  *)
```

Too many colors that are not black, and they should be. Why?

Answer (score 2):

According to the data I found, LAB is indeed not black when l=0, which is rather confusing and hard to avoid

Comment: well that's unfortunate.